# Adding specific data to specific row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a list of data that is basically filled with the computations of 9 different mathematical functions (`n log n`, `n`, `n*n`, etc) for the values 1 through 12. I am trying to have all of the results of the computations for the value of 1 in a single column, a single column for the results for the value of 2, etc until 12. How can I do this using JTable? What I have so far is:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

String col[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12" };

DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(col, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
for (Pair<String,Double> pair : val1) {
    if (pair.getX().contains("(1)")) { 
        Object[] objs = {pair.getX() + "" + pair.getY()};               
        tableModel.addRow(objs);
    }
    if (pair.getX().contains("(2)")) { 
        Object[] test = {pair.getX() + "" + pair.getY()};               
        tableModel.addRow(test);
    }       
}
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(900,300);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

When I do `tableModel.addRow(test)`, this continues adding the results in the first column. How do I get it to move that data into the second column?

Comment: Have your tried setting the row count of the model to the expected length (12) and using `setValueAt`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried this and I actually do get access to inputting information in the second column, however, when trying to do `tableModel.setValueAt(test, 0, 2)`, I receive a Ljava.lang.Object;@21195f21 error message probably because the object `test` requires 9 rows to display all the data. Is there a way to specify to use the first 9 rows in the second column using setValueAt?

Comment: Don't put `test` in the cell, put the actual value you want in that cell.  Other wise you need to re-arrange your data